# Why is sheaf Hom left-exact?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory

Fix a ringed space $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ and two sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{G}$, then we can define the sheaf $\mathscr{H}\!\mathit{om}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathscr{F},\mathscr{G})$ by setting $$\mathscr{H}\!\mathit{om}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathscr{F},\mathscr{G})(U)=\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X\vert_U}(\mathscr{F}\vert_U,\mathscr{G}\vert_U)$$ with the obvious restriction maps, so that using maps of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules $\varphi:\mathscr{G}\to\mathscr{G}'$ and $\psi:\mathscr{F}'\to\mathscr{F}$ we can induce maps $$\mathscr{H}\!\mathit{om}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathscr{F},\mathscr{G})\to \mathscr{H}\!\mathit{om}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathscr{F},\mathscr{G}')$$ and $$\mathscr{H}\!\mathit{om}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathscr{F},\mathscr{G})\to\mathscr{H}\!\mathit{om}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathscr{F'},\mathscr{G})$$ given on the open set $U$ by $$f\mapsto \varphi\vert_U\circ f$$ and $$f\mapsto f\circ\psi\vert_U$$ respectively. Now, Lemma 17.20.12 of the Stacks Project claims that any short exact sequence $$0\to\mathscr{F}_1\to\mathscr{F}_2\to\mathscr{F}_3\to 0$$ induces exact sequences $$0\to\mathscr{H}\!\mathit{om}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathscr{F_3},\mathscr{G})\to\mathscr{H}\!\mathit{om}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathscr{F_2},\mathscr{G})\to\mathscr{H}\!\mathit{om}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathscr{F_1},\mathscr{G})$$ and $$0\to\mathscr{H}\!\mathit{om}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathscr{G},\mathscr{F_1})\to\mathscr{H}\!\mathit{om}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathscr{G},\mathscr{F_2})\to\mathscr{H}\!\mathit{om}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathscr{G},\mathscr{F_3})$$ Now, I can prove that the first (nontrivial) map is injective in both cases, but I don't see how to show exactness in the middle.

Comment: All Homs in all abelian categories are left exact. This has nothing to do with ringed spaces or sheaves. I suggest you look at this at the level of generality of abeliancategories categories, to remove all irrelevant details.

Comment: The lemma above your cited lemma in the Stacks Project says that sheaf Hom is right adjoint to the tensor product.

Comment: But the sheaf Hom is not a Hom-set in an abelian category.

Comment: But right adjoints are always left exact...

Comment: Ok I understand now.

Comment: On a similar note, is the sheaf Ext balanced?

Comment: @Monstrous Moonshine What do you mean by balancing of Ext in this situation? Usually balancing of Ext means that $R^n \operatorname{Hom} (M,-) (N) \cong R^n \operatorname{Hom} (-,N) (M)$, when one works in a category with enough injectives and projectives.

Comment: @Monstrous Moonshine in this case, you can't obtain $\operatorname{Ext}^n (\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})$ / $\mathcal{Ext}^n (\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})$ by deriving $\operatorname{Hom} (-,\mathcal{G})$ / $\mathcal{Hom} (-,\mathcal{G})$, because we don't have enough projectives.

Comment: Still, there remains a question: If $\mathcal F$ admits a free or projective resolution (which can happen even if not all objects admit such), can you use it to compute $\mathcal{Ext}^n(\mathcal F,\mathcal G)$? That is a legit question. It is definitely wrong for $\operatorname{Ext}$ because we have $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal O_X,-)=\Gamma(X,-)$, which has non-trivial higher cohomology. But is it true for $\mathcal{Ext}$? I would say the answer is yes for free resolutions.

Comment: @MooS, a little late to this, but Hartshorne Prop. III.6.5 answers your last question: you can calculate the ext sheaves via a locally free free resolution.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\homs{\mathcal{H}om}
\def\hom{\operatorname{Hom}}
\def\O{\mathcal{O}}
\def\F{\mathcal{F}}
\def\G{\mathcal{G}}
$As of current date, there is no "Lemma 17.20.12 of the Stacks Project". Maybe the numbering has changed since you asked the question five years ago. The result I think you are quoting is tag [`01CO`](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01CO), whose proof is ommited .

As an alternative to the argument that the sheaf hom is a right adjoint and so it preserves limits (MooS pointed this out in the comments), we can give the following argument:

In the statement of [`01CO`](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01CO), the complexes of sheaves of modules
$$
\tag{1}\label{1}
0\to\homs_{\O_X}(\F,\G)\to\homs_{\O_X}(\F_1,\G)\to\homs_{\O_X}(\F_2,\G),\\
$$
$$
\tag{2}\label{2}
0\to\homs_{\O_X}(\F,\G)\to\homs_{\O_X}(\F,\G_1)\to\homs_{\O_X}(\F,\G_2),
$$
are exact on sections, i.e., for each open set $U\subset X$, the sequences
$$
0\to\hom_{\O_U}(\F|_U,\G|_U)\to\hom_{\O_U}(\F_1|_U,\G|_U)\to\hom_{\O_U}(\F_2|_U,\G|_U),\\
\phantom{a}\\
0\to\hom_{\O_U}(\F|_U,\G|_U)\to\hom_{\O_U}(\F|_U,\G_1|_U)\to\hom_{\O_U}(\F|_U,\G_2|_U),
$$
are exact. This follows from the fact that $\mathsf{Mod}(\O_U)$ is an abelian category and tag [`05AA`](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05AA). Now use the fact that taking filtered colimits of abelian groups is an exact operation (tag [`00DB`](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00DB)) to conclude that the sequences \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} are exact on stalks, and thus exact.